# Is there a way to see if a SQL 2012 Replication publication is marked for initilazation and a way to unmark it?

Tags: replication

We have a SQL (2102) Replication Database with a Realtime DB being the Publisher and a Historical Db as the Subscriber. All of the Tables/Articles have the setting of Do Not Delete. Thereby the Realtime DB is maintained with a max data of say 2 weeks but the historical DB will just keep growing. We need to add a couple of tables/articles and have seen the mini-snapshot discussed and it does work fine. However I have come to a worrisome condition. If ever a snapshot is initialized, all of the history will be lost! Bad design I suppose. But is there a way to check to see if a publication is marked for initialization and a way to clear it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has some documentation on Initializing and Reinitializing Transactional Replication.

[Initialize a Subscription with a Snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151795(v=sql.110).aspx)

[Initialize a Transactional Subscription Without a Snapshot](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151705(v=sql.110).aspx)

[Reinitialize Subscriptions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152771(v=sql.110).aspx)

[Snapshot Options](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151750(v=sql.110).aspx)

From your concern over lost data, you might want to investigate the **Snapshot Options**. Note this option: *Specify an **alternate snapshot folder location** instead of or **in addition to** the default snapshot folder location.*

Comment: Thanks,I did find: To initialize a subscription with a backup, which was helpful. However I did not find anything about undoing a manual marking for initialization. I'll set this as answered.

Comment: Sorry for being a newbie but I couldn't figure out how to accept as answer...